# Binding key combination to other key

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, arch-linux

I am using i3wm on Arch and I want use Win as my mod key.

This does not work, because it seems that intern that the key combination Win+Shift gives the key SunPros - `keycode 138 (keysym 0x1005ff70, SunProps)`. And other keys like Win+C are also mapped to XF86Copy and some other like that.

I still want to use the combination `Win+Shift+Q` (for instance), but for this I have to tell the computer, when it sees SunPros clicked, to understand it as Win+Shift.

As far as I know xmodmap can only swap keys with other keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your mod key as the Win key in your i3 config file. 
There should be a line in your config file that looks like this:

```
set $mod Mod4
```

Mod4 is the Win key as listed [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap#Modifier_keys). Once that is done, you can bind keys by using

```
bindsym $mod+Q exec "some command"
```

Or

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+1 move container to workspace 1
```